# How to fetch the subtitle text at a specific timestamp in html5 video player

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So Ive this html5 video player code which plays video and loads subtitle. It also attempts to show the subtitle at an exact timestamp, so that the text at that timestamp could be read into a variable and submitted to a database. **[THE JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nwyejoz5/)**

But I want to display the subtitle text dynamically so that as soon as I press submit, the subtitle at that particular timestamp gets available to be saved in a database, in a frame somewhat like this :-

```
<p>Subtitle_tstamp: <span id="s_tstamp"></span></p>
<input name="s_tstamp" id="hidden-tstamp" type="hidden">
<p class="submit">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_form">Submit</button>
<p>
```

I can see "hidden-tstamp: " , but subtitle isnt displaying in front of it . I want it to be displayed under the video in front of "hidden-tstamp: " like in [this tutorial](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/video/track/index.html). And when I click submit, the subtitle text at that time should get passed/saved into a variable for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

The `<track>` element has the [cuechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack/cuechange_event) event. This event fires every time whenever a subtitle has been changed. That means when a text shows and when a text disappears.

Select your `<track>` and `<input>` element, listen for the `cuechange` event and based on the current `text` that is showing update the `value` of your `input`.

In the event handler check if there are any `activeCues`. These are stored in an array. So if the array is empty no text is showing, if it is not select the first key and select the `text` property of it. That is the current subtitle. Set the `<input>`' value to the `text` property.

All of the data of about the track is stored in the `event.target.track` property of the `cuechange` event.

```
// Select the track and the input element.
const video = document.getElementById('my_video_1');
const track = video.querySelector('track');
const stamp = document.getElementById('hidden-tstamp');

// Listen for the cuechange event.
// Check if there are active cues and use them as value.
track.addEventListener('cuechange', event => {
  const currentCues = event.target.track.activeCues;
  if (currentCues.length) {
    stamp.value = currentCues[0].text;
  } else {
    stamp.value = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Emiel, but being a noob a dont know if I should just use this code as it is. Copy pasting it didnt work. Could you pls help me with the working code!!  Highly obliged !!

Comment: I didn't select the video correctly. I've modified the code. Try it again.

Comment: Thanks, Ive updated my entire code as per your suggestion in my question. Its still not working as desired. Could you pls have a look.

Comment: Can you specify what is not working? Is the console showing any errors?

Comment: I can see "hidden-tstamp: " , but subtitle isnt displaying in front of it . I want it to be displayed under the video in front of "hidden-tstamp: " like in this tutorial --> https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/video/track/index.html    . And when I click submit, the subtitle text at that time should get passed/saved into a variable for further processing.

Comment: I've been very sleepy and made a typo. The right value was not being read and set into the `hidden-tstamp` input. Could you provide an environment where I am able to test the code you've provided. I see that you've removed the `<video>` HTML. Could you place it back? And add the link you just provided to the original question so that others can help as well to get you to where you need to be.

Comment: Emiel could you pls help!!

Comment: Please fix the fiddle first or try an alternative, like your own hosting. The subs are not loading because of CORS and there is a different error in your code you previously didn't share. Specifically in the `jumplink` section. I've tested my code above with the tutorial you gave and it works there.

Comment: Posted again here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119011/how-to-pass-a-dynamic-subtitle-text-value-to-a-database-from-html5-video-player]