# How to pass a dynamic subtitle text value to a database from html5 video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive created a html5 video player with subtitle. Now I want the user to be able to press submit and the subtitle text at that particular timestamp should go to a database. 
I tried several ways but none of them are working for me as Im unable to even fetch the subtitle text at a particular timestamp.

```
<html>
<script src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script> 

    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 

            $("button").click(function() { 

              //here the value is stored in variable.  
                var x = document.getElementById("subt").getAttribute('value') ;

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 
            }); 

        }); 
    </script> 



<body>

<section>
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="400" height="268"
data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 4] }'>
<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<track src='https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/video/track/video-subtitles-en.vtt'  kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English" default>
</video>

 <form>
 <div >
 <input type="hidden" id="hidden-sub" />

 <div id="subt">test1
   <button> 
      Get the value of the input field 
   </button> 
   <p id="demo"></p> 
 </div>

 <div>asdf2</div>

 </div>
 </form>
</section>


<script>
if (!document.createElement('track').track)  {
  alert('<track is not available in your browser.');
}

var video = document.querySelector('video');
var span1 = document.querySelector('section > div :first-child');
var span2 = document.querySelector('section > div :last-of-type');

var track = video.textTracks[0];
track.mode = 'hidden';

console.log(track);
var idx = 0;

track.oncuechange = function(e) {

  var cue = this.activeCues[0];
  //EDIT//
  $('#demo').text(cue.text);
  $('#hidden-sub').val(cue.text);
  if (cue) {
    if (idx == 0) {
      span2.className = '';
      span1.classList.remove('on');
      span1.innerHTML = '';
      span1.appendChild(cue.getCueAsHTML());
      span1.classList.add('on');
    } else {
      span1.className = '';
      span2.classList.remove('on');
      span2.innerHTML = '';
      span2.appendChild(cue.getCueAsHTML());
      span2.classList.add('on');
    }

    idx = ++idx % 2;
  }
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can see the subtitles, but the submit button isnt fetching the text when i click submit. It restarts playing the video with no subtitle text being fetched.  Atleast it should fetch the text and show "The following text '1234' has been submitted"

Comment: someone pls help me on this !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden input field inside your from and set subtitle text as its value. The from might look something like this

```
<form>
<div >
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden-sub" />
<div id="subt">test1
  <button> 
      Get the value of the input field 
  </button> 
  <p id="demo"></p> 
</div>

<div>asdf2</div>

</div>
</form>
```

And on track change method you can update the input field value

```
track.oncuechange = function(e) {

var cue = this.activeCues[0];
  // console.log(cue);
  $('#demo').text(cue.text);
  $('#hidden-sub').val(cue.text);
  //rest of your code
  //----
};
```

If you want to update this value for a specific time you can do something like this

```
track.oncuechange = function(e) {

var cue = this.activeCues[0];
// console.log(cue);
if (cue.startTime == '2.935') {
   $('#demo').text(cue.text);
   $('#hidden-sub').val(cue.text);
 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, as per your suggestion Ive updated the code but still I cant see current subtitle text. Also when I click on the button, the video restarts playing again.